# Accessing individual part of MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

how can I access a particular part of my mysql_query? I'm attempting to do this with the code below, but to no avail. Any help would be most appreciated!

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT id,type FROM stuff WHERE stuffID = '$stuffID'");

   echo $rs['type']; <------ tried here

   // Add the rows to the array 
   while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
   $arr[] = $obj;
   }
 echo $arr['type']; <----- also tried here
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() if you're on older mysql.  try mysqli, its better

Comment: try PDO it even better than mysqli because have better db engines support also remember about casting variables to target type. If it's stuffID you should do $stuffID = (int) $stuffID; to be sure that it is an integer. Read about sql injection http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access the row until you've fetched it.

```
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    // NOTE: $arr[] = $obj, is the same as array_push($arr, $obj),
    // I dont think you want that
    $arr = $obj; // save the row

    echo $obj->type; // you are fetching an object, not an array
}

echo $arr->type;  // you can access it here too
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this looks great. However, why don't I need quotes?

Comment: @Mobie: Because you are fetching an [object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php), not an array.  If you want to use `$arr['type']`, then use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead.

Comment: sorry, I meant why don't I need quotes around $obj->type; as in around type?

Comment: @Mobie: I just explained it.  You are using mysql_fetch_**object**, not mysql_fetch_**array**.

Comment: what do you think about this talk of using mysqli or PDO?

Comment: @Mobie: You should look into switching.  It's more secure, and also mysql_* will be deprecated soon.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: thanks for the link. And as someone far wiser than I, would you recommend mysqli or PDO?

Comment: @Mobie: I, personally, use MySQLi.  I think it's slightly easier.  But, PDO can be used for other databases as well (not must MySQL), whereas MySQLi is only for MySQL.